# Laravel Socialite google login transfers to login page again

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-socialite

I am try to integrate Google login with my application. Its working fine but it send your user back to login screen after google authentication. But when I click on the google login again it behaves like the user is already logged in. I dont want want the user to fall back to login when we comeback from google. Following are my files for controller and routes.

LoginController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        /*
         * Remove the socialite session variable if exists
         */

        \Session::forget(config('access.socialite_session_name'));

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect('/login');
    }

    /**
     * Get the failed login response instance.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $errors = [$this->username() => __('auth.failed')];

        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json($errors, 422);
        }

        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors($errors);
    }

    /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param mixed                    $user
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $errors = [];

        if (config('auth.users.confirm_email') && !$user->confirmed) {
            $errors = [$this->username() => __('auth.notconfirmed', ['url' => route('confirm.send', [$user->email])])];
        }

        if (!$user->active) {
            $errors = [$this->username() => __('auth.active')];
        }

        if ($errors) {
            auth()->logout();  //logout

            return redirect()->back()
                ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
                ->withErrors($errors);
        }

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```

SocialLoginController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\Auth\User\User;
use App\Services\RoleService;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Socialite;

class SocialLoginController extends LoginController
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

    public function redirect($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->redirect();
    }

    public function googleCallback($provider)
    {
        $userSocial =   Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
        $user       =   User::where(['email' => $userSocial->getEmail()])->first();
        if($user){
            Auth::login($user,true);
            return redirect('admin/partners');

        } else {
            $user = User::create([
                'name'          => $userSocial->getEmail(),
                'email'         => $userSocial->getEmail(),
            ]);

            $user->roles()->attach([RoleService::ROLE_AUTHENTICATED]);

            return redirect('/admin');
        }
    }
}
```

routes/auth.php

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth', 'middleware' => ['force.ssl']], function () {

    // Authentication Routes...
    Route::get('login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login');
    Route::get('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');


    // Social Authentication Routes...
    Route::post('login', 'SocialController@login');
    Route::get('login/{provider}', 'SocialLoginController@redirect');
    Route::get('login/{provider}/callback', 'SocialLoginController@googleCallback');
});
```

Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenicated.php

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure                 $next
     * @param string|null              $guard
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/admin');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: you means `oauth` redirect url ?

Comment: I mean its not letting the user get into the application on first round. The user falls back to login screen and then when he clicks for google loggin it lets user get in the application

Answer (score 0):

```
return Socialite::driver($provider)->with(["prompt" => "select_account"])->redirect();
```

this is worked for me